# compiling sass with grunt produce invalid property name

Tags: sass

I don't know why but while compiling with grunt or anything there is an error called invalid property name

```
#flotTip {
    border: none !important;
    font-size: $font-size-small !important;
    line-height: 1px !important;
    @extend .tooltip-inner() !important; 
}
```

in the above code in the line-height it produces an undefined property. My task was to convert all less files into sass files. Used many solutions to convert all of them to sass as far as I can find. But this one I can't find any solution. Can anyone answer what might be the problem?

Comment: If you have another question, ask another question.  Do not modify this question to be something else, especially once you've received answers based on the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend is only for extending simple selectors, like class, element, or id.  You cannot use `!important` with `@extend`.  This is the correct way to use extend:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}

#flotTip {
    @extend .foo; 
}
```

You may be confused confusing extends with mixins, which also cannot use `!important`.  This is the correct way to use mixins:

```
@mixin foo() {
    color: red;
}

#flotTip {
    @include foo(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `line-height: 1px !important;` line looks fine. The problem is with the following line. If you're trying to include a mixin, use `@include` and don't prefix the mixin's name with `.` (dot). Also, don't put `!important` after it.

Comment: please check on the question again. Please review it as I've updated the question part.

Comment: Do **not** extend your original question with additional questions.  (And the answer is, you're prefixing mixin name with `.` again. Please try looking at your code first before asking for help.)

Comment: When downvoting, please explain the reason, especially when the answer is correct.

Comment: i didn't down voted your answer. My question is also down voted. Don't know how?

Answer (score -1):

I would guess that you are using `@extend` incorrectly. See the docs here: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#how_it_works

Comment: please check on the question again. Please review it as I've updated the question part.